# use maven-shade-plugin, but dependency classes are not in the final jar

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

In my project's pom.xml I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  ...
</dependency>
```

I would like to have my project's final built jar including the classes of above `com.my.library:MyLib` dependency, so I used [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) in the following way:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>  
              <filters>
                 <filter>
                   <artifact>com.my.library:MyLib</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>com/my/library/**</include>
                   </includes>
                 </filter>
              </filters>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, I run `mvn clean install` , my project was built successfully.

But when I check the content of **MyProject.jar** under `target/` directory, it doesn't contain classes from `com.my.library:MyLib` dependency ,why? Where am I wrong with maven-shade-plugin ?

Comment: What are you using includes? Why not starting without any include/exclude and afterwards exclude things which should not be part of the resulting jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise , because my big project has used quite many dependencies, I only want to include ONE dependency's classes in final jar, that's why I use includes instead of excludes.

Comment: @user842225: I agree that you shouldn't have to manually exclude the libraries one by one, but khmarbaise does have a point. Try it like that first to see if it gets included at all and then investigate further (and check my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Define an `<artifactSet>`:

```
<artifactSet>
    <includes>
        <include>com.my.library:MyLib</include>
    </includes>
</artifactSet>
```

And try removing the `<artifact/>` from the `<filters/>`. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

change pattern to

```
<includes>
    <include>com/my/library/**.class</include>
</includes>
```